# Почему это не работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть приложение которое имитирует подключение к другому пк.
Но почему то мне выдает ошибку. Вот ошибка:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Имран\stream_python>python connector.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connector.py", line 5, in <module>
    from virus import connect_ip
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Имран\stream_python\virus.py", line 2, in <module>
    from connector import message_print
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Имран\stream_python\connector.py", line 5, in <module>
    from virus import connect_ip
ImportError: cannot import name 'connect_ip' from 'virus' (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Имран\stream_python\virus.py)

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Имран\stream_python>
```

Вот код connector.py:

```
import pyautogui
import pymsgbox
import ctypes
import random
from virus import connect_ip
screen_number = random.randint(1,999)
message_print = 0
def console ():
    while True:
        command = input('>>')
        if command == ('screen'):
            pyautogui.screenshot('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Имран\\stream_python\\screens\\screen.png')
        elif command ==('Message'):
            message_print = input('Введите сообщение:')



#ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, u"Conneted", u"Connector") 


ip = pymsgbox.prompt('Введите Ip', 'Подключение')
password = pymsgbox.prompt('Введите пароль', 'Подключение')

#password = pymsgbox.prompt('Введите пароль', 'Подключение')
print(ip)
print(password)
if ip == connect_ip:
    password = pymsgbox.prompt('Введите пароль', 'Подключение')
    if password == connect_pass:
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, u"Conneted", u"Connector") 
        console()
else:
    print('Что то пошло не так')

print(password)
```

Вот код virus.py:

```
import pymsgbox
from connector import message_print
connect_ip = 0
connect_pass = 0
connect_ip = pymsgbox.prompt('Введите будущий ип:', 'Создатель серверов') 
connect_pass = pymsgbox.prompt('Введите ващ будущий пароль', 'Создатель серверов')
while True:
    console_server = input('>>')
    while True:
        print('[New message]' + message_print)
```

Comment: Потому что циклические импорты. Когда virus загружается, он импортирует connector, а connector пытается прочитать virus.connect_ip, но его не существует, потому что virus ещё не загрузился и код `connect_ip = 0` просто не успел запуститься

Answer (score 1):

Переименуйте ваш файл и все будет в порядке.

---

*Объяснение:*

Так как ваш файл имеет имя `virus.py`, и *в том же самом файле* используете команду

```
from virus import connect_ip
```

программа питается импортировать `connect_ip` *не из библиотеки,* но хочет его найти прямо в вашей программе `virus.py` - а там его нету.

Comment: Если внимательно прочитать код из вопроса, то можно заметить, что он там есть